# file manipulation : shell script find and increment

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

```
 #something here
 port 4444

 #something here

 port 4444
```

So I have file like above , I would to find the line with word "port" and increment the number(the number can be any number - not necessary it's fixed at 4444) next to it by 1.

For example,result file should be of the form

```
 #something here
 port 4444

 #something here

 port 4445
```

Any thoughts, I think we need use sed , but not sure about incrementing it.

EDIT:
Sorry again,I thought I get answer based in sed , so didn't think about positions. Here is the exact file contents

```
$cat file
data dev-1
type client
option type tcp
option host 99.160.131.163
option nodelay on
option port 6996
end

data dev-2
type client
option type tcp
option host 99.160.131.164
option nodelay on
option port 6996
end
```

I would like to change the port number and increment it.Sorry again for inconvenience.

Comment: Sorry guy, I have changed the title ,to make my problem more clearer.
I need to edit these values inside a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'f && $2=="port"{ $NF=num} $2=="port"{ num=$NF+1; f=1 } 1 ' file
data dev-1
type client
option type tcp
option host 99.160.131.163
option nodelay on
option port 6996
end

data dev-2
type client
option type tcp
option host 99.160.131.164
option nodelay on
option port 6997
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
port=444
((port+=1))
echo $port
```

the reference [The Double-Parentheses Construct](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html)

Comment: Also: `((port++))`, but your answer doesn't address the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{p=-1}
    { if($2=="port"){if(p==-1){p=$3}else{p++};print $1,$2,p} else {print} }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl script will be:

```
$ perl -pe 'if (/^(port )(\d+)/) { $_ = "$1" . ($2+$count) . "\n" if $count; $count++; }' < aaa.txt
#something here
port 4444

#something here


port 4445
port 4446
```

input data:

```
$ cat aaa.txt
#something here
port 4444

#something here


port 4444
port 4444
```